# Issues installing Symfony 2.8 on a Linux

Tags: php, linux, symfony

I have spend weeks trying to install Symfony on Linux...

I create a new project (Applications) .... And I wasn't able to access it with my browser.
I created a new folder, cut-paste all the files in it and deletted the folder create by Symfony. I was able to access it with my browser (using srv-web-03/Applications/). 
If I try srv-web-03/Applications/web, I can see all the file and folders in it.
If I try srv-web-03/Applications/web/something, I have a 404 error.
If I try srv-web-03/Applications/web/app.php/something, I have a blank page.
I editted the file app.php to be like app_dev.php : no change.
When I look at my apache log files I have this error :
"PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug' not found in /var/www/html/Applications/web/app.php on line 14"

I try that http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/book/installation.html#book-installation-permissions, but the result is the same.

last thing : I'm... Let say I'm a dumbass with Linux... It doesn't help.

thank you in advance

Comment: You are trying to install it on localhost ? What is your  local web server? Apache? Can  you copy/paste  your  apache conf file ?

Comment: Debugging is intended to be used in dev environement.  So when when visiting `srv-web-03/Applications/web/app.php/something` I guess you should set environement to prod. check this: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-hello-world/issues/4